# Question about weak derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about weak derivatives.

Let $u,v \in L^{1}_{loc}(U)$ (the space of locally integrable functions) for some
open set $\emptyset \neq U \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ We often say that $v$ is the $\alpha$-th ($\alpha$ is a multi index) weak derivative of $u$ if the following equation hold:
\begin{align}
\int_{U}u D^{\alpha}\varphi=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{U}v\varphi
\end{align}
for all $\varphi \in C_{0}^{\infty}(U)$ (the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $U$ )

Let $\emptyset \neq U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $C^{1}-$boundary. I want to define weak derivative of $u \in L^{1}(\overline{U})$. How should I define derivatives? I think this notion enables us to define Sobolev spaces on $\overline{U}$.

Comment: As there is a canonical isomorphism between $L^1(U) $ and $L^1(\overline{U}) $ (for the Lebesgue measure) in this case, I would just works on $L^1(U) $. I don't see what new information or different propety you can get by working on $\overline{U}$, but I may be mistaken

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let  $\Phi:L^{1}(U) \to L^{1}(\overline{U})$ be a canonical isomorphism between $L^{1}(U)$ and $L^{1}(\overline{U})$ and $u \in L^{1}(\bar{U})$. In the end, should I define $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}:=\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(u)}{\partial x_{i}}$ ?

Comment: You can, but I still don't see what you gain by working on $\overline{U}$ instead of working on $U$, what difference does it makes. If you want to study what happens at the boundary $\partial U$ you can works with the trace operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator

Comment: Thanks. I decided to define $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}:=\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}u}{\partial x_{i}}$. By working on $\overline{U}$,  $1 \in W_{0}^{1,2}(\overline{U}):=\overline{C_{0}^{\infty}(\overline{U})}^{\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,2}}}$. Therefore I am fussy about $\overline{U}$.

Comment: But $C_0^{\infty}(\overline{U}) =  C^{\infty}(U)$, so with your definition, $W^{1,2}_0(\overline{U}) = W^{1,2}(U)$

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25401/discussion-between-sharpe-and-tryss).